# Store in server only changed files and delete them after synchronisation

Tags: linux, sync, dropbox

I have two laptops (maybe one more on its way) running Ubuntu and I wish to keep certain directories synchronized.
I've considered DropBox and I'm not happy about a couple of points:

- All my sensible data, my whole life, will be permanently on the hands of a third party.
- My files would exceed the maximum storage size of a free account; all I need is synchronize a few mb of changed or added files per week. It is ridiculous to state that, in order to achieve this, I have to keep 50gb of stuff on the server.

I then came across Unison which requires both machines to be switched on for synchronisation.
If one morning I get up wanting to use laptop number 2, but in order to do so I first have to switch on laptop number 1, I'll end up using solely laptop number 1.
The last scenario is actually what's happening today.
So the question is, as the title, how to store in server only changed files and delete them after synchronisation?
Many thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Did you think to an [home cloud](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=home+cloud) system? Maybe you can find interesting those [Personal cloud considerations](https://gigaom.com/2014/03/01/how-to-set-up-your-own-personal-home-cloud-storage-system/) or [these from computerworld](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2497495/private-cloud/here--there--everywhere--3-personal-cloud-storage-systems.html) or any other from internet...

Comment: That's a very good idea I didn't know about. Thanks @Hastur
A drawback I find is that I would need to put my hands on the router security settings in order to allow remote access; I want to be able to sync also from a coffeeshop, friend house, other country (I do travel). I'm honestly not very happy with the idea of buying new hardware just because I can't find the right software. Free storage is everywhere out there, all I need is the right software; my idea seems to me very much possible

Comment: I agree with you @sunk818 , that's what Unison does. What I don't think it does, and I would be very glad if you guys proved me wrong, is uploading only changes to a specified location and use that location as reference to sync other machines. When the last machine is synced, then files can be deleted. It seems a perfectly feasible idea to me.

Comment: You can do your own _home cloud_ with old hardware and paid internet connection. Usually the bottleneck is not the hardware but the connection. BTW an old hardware maybe not designed to be used 7/24 can _eat_ a lot of energy and incur in mechanical failures... take in the right account it too. And backup always, even if new hardware!

Comment: You could encrypt before storage on DropBox using something like [CryptSync](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/CryptSync.html). If you keep at least one offline device fully synced, you're protected in case they go under. I guess you still have the space issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 50GB is a lot of data to keep synced, but if you really want to complicate your setup, you can look at [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/index.html). You can send incrementals to a server, then restore to your other machine. This assumes your second machine is exact copy of your first computer without the incremental changes. I think what you want can actually have disastrous results and think it it just better to suck it up and use a sync software such as Bittorrent Sync over hosting incrementals on a server you will retrieve from.